# Clean Corners for Subdivision

Tags: topology

I added a few support edges to get sharp edges and then merged some vertices, so the edge loops don't spread on my whole model. Now I have all quads, but the corners don't look right.

[image]

I know that I could get away with triangles on the bottom part, because it is a flat surface, but what about the pointy star trek polygon in the back?

Answer (score 1):

Going into wireframe mode shows that the subdivision creates a fold in the model.

[image]

Creasing the sides of the star trek polygon pulls the fold out.

[image]

That basically solves my problem, because the render looks right, but the topology doesn't:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this distortion is that it's a concave quad, and *Subdivision Surface* works better with clean quads. You can solve your problem with these tricks:

1. add a single edge in the middle of the quad: you won't have any distortion with *Subdivision Surface*, but the resulting mesh contains triangles

[image: solution1]

2. add this edge loops and remove the two edges marked in red, so you will keep a pure quad mesh

[image: solution2]

Comment: That's the problem: Either I have triangles or excess edge loops. I removed the green edges in the second picture, so I don't have to deal with them in unrelated parts of the mesh.